# What is wrong with my SQL Statement when creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

whats wrong with this code?

```
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
    `id` INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar,
    `image` varchar
    ) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Err:

```
#1064 - Near '
    `image` varchar
    ) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8' in Zeile 3
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

varchar **must have** a size, when you define it.

So you can choose for example 100

```
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
    `id` INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(100),
    `image` varchar(100)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```